# RCK2 Resource Compiler

Tags: verifone

I'm new to VeriFone development. I need to compile the RCK file. I have used the below command to do that, but the command doesn't show any output or generate file. It does nothing.

```
C:\eVoAps\Tools>Rck2.exe -SC:\Bill\MyApp\Source\Resource\ 
MyApp -OC:\Bill\MyApp\Output\RV\Files\Resource\MyApp -M
```

Could anyone help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you say it does nothing.  Does it at least give you an error?  If so, what is it?

If it does NOTHING, then make sure you have the following files in your C:\eVoAps\Tools folder:

- C1.DLL
- CL.EXE
- MSPDB60.DLL

If you are getting an error, then I suspect it is something close to this:

> C:\Bill\MyApp\Source\Resource\MyApp.RCK(28) : fatal error C1034:
>   devman.h: no include path set Parse Error in
>   file[C:\Bill\MyApp\Source\Resource\MyApp.RI]! Invalid token [eof] at
>   line -1 offset -1 SSYacc0105e: Error token failed, no valid token
>   ERROR! Aborting compilation!

The reason I say that is because I'm pretty sure you need to include the VMAC includes and template for it to work.  These can be found in `%EVOVMAC%\include` and `%EVOVMAC%\template`.  To *include*, use the `-J` switch:

```
C:\eVoAps\Tools>Rck2.exe -SC:\Bill\MyApp\Source\Resource\MyApp 
-OC:\Bill\MyApp\Output\RV\Files\Resource\MyApp 
-M -J%EVOVMAC%\include -J%EVOVMAC%\Template
```

(Naturally, this will need to all be on 1 line, but I'm breaking it up here to make it more legible)

Note that if you are using nmake, you can have the resource file generated as part of the build.  My make file does that with these lines:

```
$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName).res : $(ResDir)\$(ProjectName).rck
    $(EVOTOOLS)rck2 -S$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName) -O$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName) -M
```

You may have noticed that I didn't use the `-J` switches here.  That's because I've already included those paths in my project and that is captured in my build.  I believe an alternative to either of these would be

```
$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName).res : $(ResDir)\$(ProjectName).rck
    SET INCLUDE=$(INCLUDE);$(EVOVMAC)\include;$(EVOVMAC)\template
    $(EVOTOOLS)rck2 -S$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName) -O$(ResDir)\$(ProjectName) -M
```

although that depends on how your build is set up.